# Mechanism of dehydration of alcohols by iodine/triphenylphosphine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403904008329) describes the dehydration of an alcohol to form an alkene. What is the mechanism of alcohol dehydration with iodine? Why can only iodine of all the halogens be used?

Comment: Can you post an example of the kind of system you mean? In the broadest possible sense iodine can act as a Lewis acid to help the OH leave, but it would depend on the structure of the SM as to how the whole thing proceeded.

Comment: It is generally used for dehydration of alcohols.

Comment: My point is that asking for a mechanism without any indication of the structure is unlikely to yield a correct answer, as the mechanism for any process depends upon the steric and electronic demands of the molecule.  I'd also question whether iodine is considered a 'general' method for these reactions, quoting from March's Advanced Organic Chemistry: "Many other dehydrating agents159 have been used on occasion: P2O5, I2..." .. the examples I have seen of iodine used tend to be very specific examples where other more common reagents were tried and failed

Comment: I would like to see an example with mechanism where it is used. I am unable to provide one,

Comment: I'm pretty sure that iodine is effective in this way where other halogems fail because it acts as a good leaving group for the OH as @NotNicolau said. Also the iodide molecule is larger than the other halogens presenting more surface area which makes it leave easier, I think.

Comment: Marko, if you would like to see such an example, could you re-word your question to be "What is an example of a reaction and mechanism where iodine dehydrates an alcohol?"?

Comment: Do you have an example of this type reaction?

Comment: May this question be opened now or is any further correction  needed?

Comment: The mechanism possibly resembles that of the Appel reaction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appel_reaction). It is mentioned in the article that $\ce{I2}$ can be used instead of $\ce{CCl4}$. To arrive at an alkene as final product, the last step would have to be elimination instead of substitution by the halide.

Comment: Seems reasonable.